# Longest increasing subsequence using 2-3 tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

While preparing for my data structures final I came across this problem:

A - a given array of integers of length n.

Propose data structure with supports the following operations:

**Init(A)** - initialisation of the structure given the array A. Worst case complexity: O(nlogn).
**LengthOfLongest()** - returns the length of the longest monotonically increasing s of A (elements). Worst case complexity: O(1).

I know that it is a well known problem, and I'm aware of the relevant wiki article. However the solution provided there is not intuitive to me.

I was given a hint that this problem can be solved as well with 2-3 rank tree for instance.

Can someone explain me the solution using 2-3 tree?

Example:
For array A = {10,9,11,8,12,7,13}
The longest subarray is {10, 11, 12, 13} and its length is 4.

Comment: I feel like you're missing parts of the question. Couldn't you just loop through the array itself and find the longest increasing subarray in O(n) time?

Comment: What is the argument to the second function? Or it just returns the longest subarray of A? Then why is it split into two functions?

Comment: do you mean this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

Comment: Your example shows a subsequence, not a subarray

Comment: there are no `insert()`s and `remove`s in your structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-studied problem called longest increasing subsequence, which could be solved in O(n log n) time. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence